# Finding the closest or exact key in a std::map

Tags: c++

I need to create a lookup table which links a length to a time interval (both are of data type double). The keys increment linearly as they are inserted, so it will already be sorted (perhaps an unordered_map would be better?).

What I am looking for is a way to find a key that best matches the current length provided to get the time value, or even better find the two keys that surround the length (the given key is between them) so I can find the interpolated value between the two time values.

I also need the best performance possible as it will be called in real time.

EDIT:  I would have rather the following was a comment to the first answer below, but the format is hard to read.

I tried to do the following, but it seems to return the same iterator (5.6):

```
std::map<double, double> map;
map.insert(std::pair<double, double>(0.123, 0.1));
map.insert(std::pair<double, double>(2.5, 0.4));
map.insert(std::pair<double, double>(5.6, 0.8));

std::map<double, double>::iterator low, high;
double pos = 3.0;
low = map.lower_bound(pos);
high = map.upper_bound(pos);
```

How would I get 'low' to point to the last element that is < than the key used to search?

EDIT 2:
Silly me, 'low--' will do it, providing it's not the first element.

Getting there :)

Comment: Some additional information might help. What I got so far is that there is a function l = f(t). And its inverse t = f^-1(l). And you need to estimate that function from some data points and interpolate it, right? Instead of a look up table, maybe some continuously updated approximation function would serve you better.

Comment: If you only have a few entries in the map (like less than 5), linear search is normally faster than using a map in the first place. If you have more entries it might pay off to "sample" your lookup table entries with equidistant time values. Then you need not search but you can compute the index to the correct entry in your LUT.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

For this, you can use either [`std::map::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/lower_bound)

> Returns an iterator pointing to the first element that is not less than key.

or [`std::map::equal_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/equal_range)

> Returns a range containing all elements with the given key in the container.

---

In your case, if you want the closest entry, you need to check both the returned entry and the one before and compare the differences. Something like this might work

```
std::map<double, double>::iterator low, prev;
double pos = 3.0;
low = map.lower_bound(pos);
if (low == map.end()) {
    // nothing found, maybe use rbegin()
} else if (low == map.begin()) {
    std::cout << "low=" << low->first << '\n';
} else {
    prev = std::prev(low);
    if ((pos - prev->first) < (low->first - pos))
        std::cout << "prev=" << prev->first << '\n';
    else
        std::cout << "low=" << low->first << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  The search key will always be >= min and <= max, so something will be found.  With these two iterators I can work out a new time value.

Comment: One question, though.  Is std::map the fastest under the bonnet for this?  The lookup table may consist of up to 10000 elements, but I may be able to reduce this with more approximations..

Comment: A hash map (`std::unordered_map`) might be faster at looking up an exact value, but there you don't have the values ordered. So a `std::map` or a sorted `std::vector` seems to be the fastest standard container for this use case. Using a priority queue may be useful, when you always want the largest or smallest value.

Comment: Well, since I have calculated the new time, I have found I can get away with as low as 100 elements, and not lose much in the way of precision. So far so good.

Answer (score 6):

*"best performance possible"* - given you insert elements in increasing order, you can `push_back`/`emplace_back` them into a `std::vector` then use [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) - you'll get better cache utilisation because the data will be packed into contiguous address space.

Comment: Thanks, I will consider moving to a vector when I optimise it further.  Sorry I missed your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could of course use lower_bound and upper_bound, which are logarithmic in runtime. And they should do what you want.

```
std::map<double,double>::iterator close_low;
//... your_map ...
close_low=your_map.lower_bound (current_length);
```

This should give you an iterator to the the first map element whose key is < current length. Do likewise with upper_bound and you have your time surrounded.

Comment: "*Do likewise with upper_bound and you have your time surrounded."* - that would double the search time - it's generally better to simply increment the iterator to reach the great-than element or `end()` (the former must be immediately after the lower-bound, but even with a `multimap` where it might not be you'd only bother with upper-bound if there were potentially a lot of same-key elements and you didn't need/want to iterate and operate on them individually.

Answer (score 2):

The functions [`std::lower_bound()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/) and [`std::upper_bound()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/upper_bound/) would be useful here.

`lower_bound()` gives the first element that is `>=` to the value you're looking for; `upper_bound()` gives the first element that is `>` than the value.

For instance, searching for the value `5` in the following list: `{1,3,5,5,6}`<sup>1</sup> using `lower_bound()` returns the third element, while `upper_bound()` would return the fifth element.
If the two functions return the same thing `x`, then the value you're looking for is not present in the list.
The value just before it is `x-1` and the value just after it is `x`.

<sup>1</sup><sub>As pointed out by [Tony D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/410767/tony-d) in a comment, the question asked for maps, which generally do not contain duplicate elements.
I'm keeping this example though to illustrate the two functions.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Complete generic solution (original idea taken from [Olaf Dietsche](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1741542/olaf-dietsche)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28405093/4939996)):

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

template <typename T1, typename T2>
T1 findClosestKey(const std::map<T1, T2> & data, T1 key)
{
    if (data.size() == 0) {
        throw std::out_of_range("Received empty map.");
    }

    auto lower = data.lower_bound(key);

    if (lower == data.end()) // If none found, return the last one.
        return std::prev(lower)->first;

    if (lower == data.begin())
        return lower->first;

    // Check which one is closest.
    auto previous = std::prev(lower);
    if ((key - previous->first) < (lower->first - key))
        return previous->first;

    return lower->first;
}

int main () {
double key = 3.3;

std::map<double, int> data = {{-10, 1000}, {0, 2000}, {10, 3000}};

std::cout << "Provided key: " << key << ", closest key: " << findClosestKey(data, key) << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <map>

template <typename T1, typename T2>
std::map<T1, T2>::iterator nearest_key(const std::map<T1, T2>& map, T1 key) {
    auto lower_bound = map.lower_bound(key);
    auto upper_bound = lower_bound; upper_bound++;
    if (lower_bound == map.end()) return upper_bound;
    if (upper_bound == map.end()) return lower_bound;
    unsigned int dist_to_lower = std::abs((int)lower_bound->first - (int)key);
    unsigned int dist_to_upper = std::abs((int)upper_bound->first - (int)key);
    return (dist_to_upper < dist_to_lower) ? upper_bound : lower_bound;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

above is wrong. should be like this
    template

```
typename std::map<T1, T2>::const_iterator nearest_key(const std::map<T1, T2>& map, T1 key)
{
    auto lower_bound = map.lower_bound(key);
    if (lower_bound == map.end()) return --lower_bound;
    auto upper_bound = lower_bound; upper_bound++;
    if (upper_bound == map.end()) return lower_bound;
    auto dist_to_lower = lower_bound->first - key;
    auto dist_to_upper = upper_bound->first - key;
    return (dist_to_upper < dist_to_lower) ? upper_bound : lower_bound;
}
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to OP's problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve the same problem, however provided answers do not give me the correct answer. Here is a full example if someone wants

```
            template <typename T>
            class Key
            {
                public:
                    T x;
                    T y;
                    explicit Key(T x_, T y_): x(x_), y(y_){}
                    bool operator<( const Key<T> right) const{
                        if((x == right.x) && (y == right.y)){
                            return false;
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                    T operator-( const Key<T> right) const{
                        return std::sqrt(std::pow(x-right.x, 2) + std::pow(y-right.y, 2));
                    }
            };

           int main(int argc, char **argv)
              {

                std::map<Key<double>, double> pixel_mapper;

                Key<double> k1(400,5);
                Key<double> k2(4,5);
                Key<double> k3(4,5);
                Key<double> k4(4667,5);
                Key<double> k5(1000,5);

                pixel_mapper.insert(std::pair<Key<double>, double>(k2, 5));
                pixel_mapper.insert(std::pair<Key<double>, double>(k3, 5));
                pixel_mapper.insert(std::pair<Key<double>, double>(k4, 5));
                pixel_mapper.insert(std::pair<Key<double>, double>(k1, 5));

                auto it = std::min_element( pixel_mapper.begin(), pixel_mapper.end(),
                      [&](const auto &p1, const auto &p2)
                      {
                        return std::abs(p1.first - k5) < std::abs(p2.first - k5);
                      });

                std::cout<< it->first.x << "," << it->first.y << std::endl;

                return 0;

                }
```

Here, we can use [std:min_element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46285345/c-how-to-find-the-key-of-a-map-that-has-the-closest-value-of-a-given-value) to get the closest in case exact key is not present